# check optional rule is null or not

Tags: antlr

Say I have such grammar (the target language is C):

```
mycmd : cmd_name  option? arg1
```

Since "option" is optional, if I direct access it like this -

```
mycmd : cmd_name  option? arg1
{ add_option($option.text); }
```

The program will crash, the generated C code is

```
add_option(option->getText(option));
```

Here "option" is NULL.

I experimented the following

```
mycmd : cmd_name  option? arg1
{ if ($option != NULL) { add_option($option.text);} }
```

This works fine.

But I googled around and found that the recommended way is to pre-declare some bool, set it to true in sub-rule and check its value in action. I do not like it since it renders harder to read grammar.

The question is, is it just my luck that checking "$option" against NULL works for me? Is there any other recommended way so that I can keep the grammar and action separate?

I am using ANTLR3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking against NULL is appropriate, or you could instead put the action inside an optional subrule.

```
mycmd : cmd_name 
        (option {add_option($option.text);} )? 
        arg1
```

Comment: I check the generated Parser.c, I believe the original code is not right -

Comment: I check the generated Parser.c, I believe putting the action inside the optional subrule is the right solution, "option" becomes a function in Parser.c, it does not make sense to check it against NULL.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following:

```
{ if ($option) { add_option($option.text); } }
```